# how to accesses %ROWTYPE% from java side using function call

Tags: java, oracle

i have a funtion in oracle db like this.

```
  create or replace function pin_sf_get_pin_detail
    (p_pin in varchar2)
    return pin_tm_form%rowtype
    as

    l_pin_record pin_tm_form%rowtype;
    begin
    select * into l_pin_record from pin_tm_form
    where pin = p_pin;
    return(l_pin_record);
    end;
```

and i want to call this function from java side, for that i have written a small program which is not working..here is my java programm.

```
final String typeName = "pin_details";
         final  String typeTableName  = "pin_tm_form";
         Connection con=ConnectionTest.getConnection();
         final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName.toUpperCase(),con);        
         final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();

        CallableStatement cst=(OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{?=call pin_sf_get_pin_detail(?)}");
        cst.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR,typeTableName.toUpperCase());
        cst.setString(2,"505460");
        cst.execute();
            Object  [] data = (Object[]) ((java.sql.Array) cst.getObject(1)).getArray();
                 for(Object tmp : data) {  
                     Struct row = (Struct) tmp; 
                     int idx = 1;  
                     for(Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {
                        if(metaData.getColumnName(idx).equalsIgnoreCase("FIRST_NAME")) 
                        {
                        System.out.println((String)attribute);
                        }

                     }
                 }
```

i created a type as Pin_details in oracle.
here my doubt is cst.registerOutParameter what i have to pass as second argument  i tried with Types class all constants when i try with Types.ARRAY
It given invalid name pattern: Pin.Pin_tm_FORM but this table is there in same schema.
when i use Types.VARCHAR it given

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
    PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

i am just trying with alternate arguments but is really don't know what i have to pass and how it will work .can anybody please help in this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing %ROWTYPE of Stored Procedure from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141289/accessing-rowtype-of-stored-procedure-from-java)

Comment: thanks for your reply can you please elaborate the answer